# Write bunch of hashes to a json file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, hash

Whats the right approach to write number of hashesh to a json file that can be parsed effeciently later on.
e.g:

```
hash1 = {:a=>1,:b=>'foo'}
hash2 = {:c=>3,:b=>'bar'}
...
hashN = {...}
```

---

```
File.open("data.json", "a") { |io|  io.write(hash1.to_json)}
```

I can write a comma after each hash to the file, but this is not looking nice to me.. is it a better way to do it?

Comment: You have a bunch of hashes and you want to convert them to JSON and save that JSON in a file?

Comment: @muistooshort: Yeah, and then I want to be able to parse the json file later on..

Comment: Why adding a comma after each document is not looking good?

Answer (score 3):

> that can be parsed effeciently later on.

You will want to put your hashes in a list so that later you can load and parse everything in one sweep:

```
require 'json'

arr = []
arr << {:a=>1,:b=>'foo'}
arr << {:c=>3,:b=>'bar'}

json_str = arr.to_json

File.open("yourfile", 'w') { |file| file.write(json_str) }
```

Later on to load:

```
contents = File.read('yourfile')
arr = JSON.parse(contents)
```

Comment: As far as I undestand @tokhi does not want to create an array first. He needs some kind of streaming...

Comment: What happens if some of the hashes which you pass have the same keys?

Comment: Each hash in the array is independent from the others, and so can have the same key without a problem.